# How to deploy react with express to heroku

Tags: reactjs, express, heroku

I setup a reactjs and express environment from scratch. I ditched the webpack-dev-server and just use `webpack --watch` for the `npm start` it's working fine it reads the changes. I can receive my react data to my express server without errors. But how would i deploy this to heroku? I am new to back-end and this is my first time using react with a backend. I hope you can help me thank you..

package.json

```
{
  "name": "react-scratch",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack --watch"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "react",
      "es2015"
    ]
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "body-parser": "^1.18.2",
    "express": "^4.16.2",
    "mongodb": "^3.0.4",
    "react": "^16.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.4",
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "nodemon": "^1.17.1",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "webpack": "^4.1.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^2.0.11",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.1"
  }
}
```

webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = {
    entry: [
            './src/index.js'
        ],
    output: {
        path: __dirname + '/dist',
        publicPath: '/',
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    devServer: {
        contentBase: './dist'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: ['babel-loader']
            }

        ]
    },
    resolve: {
       extensions: ['*', '.js', '.jsx']
     }
}
```

Server

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist', 'index.html'));
})
```

Folder Structure

```
-dist
 - bundle.js
 - index.html
-node_modules
-server
 -server.js
-src
 -index.js
 -App.js
```

Comment: Have you read the manual here https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-nodejs

Comment: Are you using git repo ?

Comment: @Aaqib i am using git repo i tried to follow heroku guide but i get application error

Answer (score 1):

Hi i m new to Heroku too,
  i spent two days reading and trying to deploy a full-stack application, consisting
  of '`reacjs + expressjs + nodejs + mongodb`'.
  I see that you also use `expressjs`, so you might later need a db also. :)

Things are little complicated as many tools need to be sync in order to work
  all together.

**Quick answer**:

Heroku has a detailed but long documentation about that and also provides an example
    Node application, ready to download it locally, check the code, and deploy 
    it to Heroku, and see it live.

> Here (https://elements.heroku.com/buttons/mongolab/hello-mongoose)

**How i deal with all the full-stack lifecycle.**

Below are **my steps** on how i succeeded **Heroku deploy(fetch some data from backend to the client)**.
[image]

link '/': https://damp-brook-72767.herokuapp.com/
  link '/users': https://damp-brook-72767.herokuapp.com/users
  link '/products': https://damp-brook-72767.herokuapp.com/products

1. Create express skeleton with `'express-generator'`
   `$ express shop`.   Creates a simple expressjs app.
   Inside the express i create some routes.
2. Create the reactjs app with `'create-react-app'`
   `$ create-react-app client`.    I run this command into the /shop folder
   `$ npm run eject`.      Eject the hidden folders 'scripts' & 'config'
3. Create the Heroku application either with `Heroku CLI` or from `Heroku.com`
4. Create a free account on `mlab.com`.
   As soon we create a new db, we get the connection string,
   e.g. `mongodb://<dbuser>:<dbpassword>@ds133630.mlab.com:33630/db`
5. Dont run locally, `$ npm run start`, because there will be 
   a CORS issue with the server `'https://damp-brook-72767.herokuapp.com'.`
   I havent solve that yet.
6. Since everything is in place.

   1. Check first **NOT** to be any errors, when execute `'$ npm run build'`
      locally.
   2. Commit any changes to 'master' branch
   3. Push to Heroku master
   4. Cross our fingers and open the webpage on Heroku.
7. That's it, except if i forgot something. I have my test project, also, on github.

> Here (https://github.com/tornado1979/fullstack-shop)

Hope this helps, good luck.